# What the difference between referencing a fragment by the Fragment super class or your extended Fragment class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I don't seem to understand what the differences/benefits are when initializing your fragment class between these two options:

```
Fragment fragmentDetails = (fragment_details) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(class_Consts.TAG_FRAGMENT_DETAILS);
```

or

```
fragment_details fragmentDetails = (fragment_details) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(class_Consts.TAG_FRAGMENT_DETAILS);
```

I remember reading that one allows a null check, while the other doesn't.. but i'm afraid i'm not sure what to search in order to grasp this fully. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the methods you'll see during compilation stage.

Declaring

```
Fragment fragmentDetails
```

you won't have access to `fragment_details` custom methods, if any. So in most situations you'd probably prefer the second option.

PS: remember to stick to java convention for naming classes; `fragment_details` should be `FragmentDetails`.